# Confused internal and external use case diagram

Tags: uml, external, visio, internals, visual-paradigm

I just got an assignment one of the questions is asking me to create 2 use case diagrams for a retailer database one internal and external however I'm not sure what the different is between them and the different use cases that they will have?

Scenario 2: A retailer company
A retailer company have more than 1000 stores across UK. Each store has their own selling PC which can update the selling information to centre warehouse database as well as local warehouse database. For advanced features, the retailer company would like to allow each store manager to enable analysing his/her own store performance on selling. The central company can have analysis for overall performance and other issues on salaries, goods providers and so on.

The report should have use case diagrams to describe what the database system functions are.

May seem pretty easier to most people how ever I am still learning and this is stressing me out! please help thank you**strong text**

Comment: I guess you should ask your instructor what he/she means with in-/external UCs since that is no common term.

Comment: Yeah I just did.. waiting on a email back and i agree it is not a common term that is why im like wt* do i do maybe im over thinking but i dont want to get anything wrong on my first assignment.

Comment: Strange exam questions are popular here. I often ask myself what those "teachers" have learnt so they think they can teach something.

Comment: By definition Use Cases describe the expected or real behaviour of a system with respect to its external actors, so this doesn't make sense to me. What they may be after is a Use Case model and then a function model, the latter being a description of internal system behaviour (e.g. state chart, sequence chart, timing diagram something like that). Would be interested to hear what your tutor say's they're after.

Comment: More clarification on assignment 1 part A
First, there is no complete right or wrong answers/solutions for your assignment

Secondly, you should work on selected scenario to identify what the business need that is part of your analysis, again there is no right or wrong analysis but reasonable or not reasonable bass on common sense.
Thirdly, after you got analysis report, then you can think who are the internal users (e.g. business data user or data management maintainer) and external user who just uses application to get information from database e.g. customers, sellers and so on.

Comment: Just really overthinking tbh keep changing my diagrams because the scenario is just still unclear to me i can't figure out many internal and external users regarding to the scenario..